# Laravel delete button, delete one model, but update the other model (for inventory management)

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am trying to learn Laravel by understanding a [laravel inventory project](https://github.com/sanz/laravel-inventory).

I found one bug in the project. When a finalized receipt/sale is deleted, the number of stock for each item does not update. So I want to fix it.

Upon finalizing a receipt/sale, it does two updates. One for receipt/sale and the other for the number of stock.

What I want to do is NOT update and update, but delete and update upon deleting finalized receipt or sale. In other words, when clicking the delete button for finalized sale or receipt, I also want to update the number of the stock.

I am assuming I need to define a custom delete function in  Receipt/Sale Model and then also make another function in the Receipt/Sale controller that actually does delete and update.

Another way is to use if/else statement in view and make function in the Receipt/Sale controller that does delete and update.

I am not sure, which way is the best practice or how to implement it.
Please help.

Here is a code for finalizing a receipt:

```
// ReceiptController.php

    public function finalize(Receipt $receipt)
    {
        $receipt->finalized_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $receipt->save();

     
        foreach($receipt->products as $receivedproduct) {

            $receivedproduct->product->stock += $receivedproduct->stock;
            $receivedproduct->product->stock_defective += $receivedproduct->stock_defective;
            $receivedproduct->product->save();

        }

        return back()->withStatus('Receipt successfully completed.');
    }
```

And this is for finalizing a sale:

```
// Sale Controller.php

    public function finalize(Sale $sale)
    {
        $sale->total_amount = $sale->products->sum('total_amount');

        foreach ($sale->products as $sold_product) {
            $product_name = $sold_product->product->name;
            $product_stock = $sold_product->product->stock;
            if($sold_product->qty > $product_stock) return back()->withError("The product '$product_name' does not have enough stock. Only has $product_stock units.");
        }

        foreach ($sale->products as $sold_product) {
            $sold_product->product->stock -= $sold_product->qty;
            $sold_product->product->save();
        }

        $sale->finalized_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $sale->client->balance -= $sale->total_amount;
        $sale->save();
        $sale->client->save();

        return back()->withStatus('The sale has been successfully completed.');
    }
```

As you can assume, each model eventually directs to the product model in order to update the number of stock.

Receipt -> ReceivedProduct -> Product

```
//ReceivedProduct.php

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReceivedProduct extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'receipt_id', 'product_id', 'stock', 'stock_defective'
    ];

    public function receipt()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Receipt');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Sale -> SoldProduct -> Product

```
//SoldProduct.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SoldProduct extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'sale_id', 'product_id', 'price', 'qty', 'total_amount'
    ];
    
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
    public function sale()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Sale');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by the code provided below.
A simple if statement added to Receipt/SaleController.php, destroy function solved the problem.

```
// ReceiptController.php
public function destroy(Receipt $receipt)
    {
        if ($receipt->finalized_at)
        {
            foreach($receipt->products as $receivedproduct) {
                $receivedproduct->product->stock -= $receivedproduct->stock;
                $receivedproduct->product->stock_defective -= $receivedproduct->stock_defective;
                $receivedproduct->product->save();
            }
        }
        $receipt->delete();
        return redirect()
            ->route('receipts.index')
            ->withStatus('Receipt successfully removed.');
    }
```

```
// SaleController.php

public function destroy(Sale $sale)
    {
        if ($sale->finalized_at){
            foreach ($sale->products as $sold_product) {
                $sold_product->product->stock += $sold_product->qty;
                $sold_product->product->save();
            }
            $sale->client->balance += $sale->total_amount;
            $sale->client->save();
        }

        $sale->delete();

        return redirect()
            ->route('sales.index')
            ->withStatus('The sale record has been successfully deleted.');
    }
```